# Shared Pointer Across Child Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a shared pointer in a base class.

```
#ifndef ROOM_HPP
#define ROOM_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include "Pocket.hpp"


using namespace std;

    class Room
    {
    protected:
        Room *up;
        Room *down;
        Room *left;
        Room *right;
        string name;

        shared_ptr<Pocket> p{ new Pocket() };
```

The shared pointer points to...

```
#ifndef POCKET_HPP
#define POCKET_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin; 
using std::string;



class Pocket
{
private:
    vector<string> pocket;

public:
    //constructor
    Pocket();
    void addPocket(string);
    string getPocket();

};



#endif
```

I have this shared pointer in two child classes. But when I make a change to the vector in one child class the change is not reflected in the second child class. Shouldn't this work with a shared pointer?

I'm basically trying to create a vector that can be shared across different classes, and having a really hard time accomplishing this.

Comment: Please prepare a [mcve] demonstrating the unexpected behavior.  Remember to take out unrelated stuff.

Comment: How should the `std::shared_ptr` be shared between your child class instances?

Comment: Trying to access the same vector across all child classes. If I add a value to the vector in one class, I'd like to be able to see that value in all other child classes.

Comment: As from your previous questions it looks like you have a misconception about the relation between classes and the relation between class instances. The instances of child classes aren't magically connected to share data at runtime. For such case you'll need to have a `static` member of this vector in your base class.

Answer (score 2):

```
shared_ptr<Pocket> p{ new Pocket() };
```

^ This is called every time a Room is created, creating multiple, unconnected Pocket objects. Calling it "shared pointer" doesn't change that, each Room is still making a distinct Pocket object of it's own.

The call to "new Pocket" needs to happen once, i.e. outside any individual Room. Then any Rooms that share the same Pocket can have their shared pointers set to point at it.

Your alternative is to make "Pocket p" a static variable shared by all Rooms, but this is less flexible since subsets of Rooms won't be able to have their own Pockets